# A gradle task command line options

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

In the section [11.6.3](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:obtaining_information_about_your_build) of the gradle manual page were mentioned that we can use command line option in gradle task.

> This information includes the full task path, the task type, *possible*
>   *commandline options* and the description of the given task.

But my question is how can we specify the options in task? Could anyone give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look a the following *build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task lol(type: JavaExec) {}
```

When `gradle -q help --task lol` is run the following output occurs:

```
Detailed task information for lol

Path
     :lol

Type
     JavaExec (org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec)

Options
     --debug-jvm     Enable debugging for the process. The process is started suspended and listening on port 5005. [INCUBATING]

Description
     -
```

So this is how option looks like: `--debug-jvm`

[Here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/ccddc438ce09293d84030ebe31668d739c8a228a/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/tasks/JavaExec.java) You can find how it's implemented - configuring an `Option` not an `Option` itself. `org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.options.Option` is a part of internal gradle API. And it seems that it's still an incubating feature.